# Python 3 nested While loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have created a function to ask for input from the user to input the numbers of hours worked for a day, the whole thing returns right besides if an incorrect value is entered it does not display its error message if the value entered is less than zero of greater than 24 it just asks for input again.

```
def hours_for_days(week_no,day):
  i = -1
  input_string = "Enter number of hours for week " + str(week_no) + " " + day + ": "
  while i <0
    work_time = rawinput(input_string)
    try:
      i = int(work_time)
    except ValueError:
      print("Enter a number: ")
    else:
      while 24 < i
        work_time = rawinput(input_string)
      try:
        i = int(work_time)
      except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number: ")
      else:
        if i < 0
          print("Enter a number between 0 and 24")
        if i > 24
          print("Enter a number between 0 and 24")
```

Comment: This is more like an affirmation than a question.

Comment: Ok then to clarify, how do I get the error message "enter a number between 0 and 24" to print

Comment: @Gunnerlc *"the whole thing returns right "* Are you sure? There are quite a few syntax errors in the code. Maybe you posted the wrong version of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add:

```
while 1:   
    work_time = rawinput(input_string)
    try:
        i = int(work_time)
        if not (0 <= i <= 24):
            raise(IndexError)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number: ")
    except IndexError:
        print("Number must be between 0 and 24")
```

Comment: cheers that worked for if the number is below 0 and requested a new number and displayed the message, but if the number was above 24 then it displayed the message and moved on to the next day.

Comment: No it doesn't. Check your indentation. Also, you can make a custom Error to not use IndexError